# What's the location of a personal 'gtkrc' file in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: gtk, settings, cursor, personalization, gtkrc

Good day everyone! I am currently writting a software that makes easy to change default cursor theme with a few clicks. At this point it works well, but applications like Firefox or Lazarus IDE remain with the DMZ-White cursor, everything else is ok. I noticed that when I change the default cursor using my software, and later change the 'personalized' cursor theme using Ubuntu Tweak, it does the job, and the new theme is now applied everywhere.

So, what file is need to modify in order to change 'personal' cursor theme? If my software can do this, that would be great!

I found that 'gtkrc' is a file where settings of GTK+ are stored. I searched in my home folder but I can't find yet. Can you help me with this, noble people of Ubuntu? :)

Answer (score 1):

What I do is open a terminal and use this command:

```bash
sudo update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme
```

You should get a list of numbered cursor themes, simply choose the number of the theme you want to use, hit enter, then log off and log back on.